# HTML Tables - How can cells below a large image be resized?

Tags: html, image, html-table

How can multiple table cells below a large image be resized to fit directly below the image?

Here is an example of the issue I'm talking about. In this example there is a large image at the top of the table followed by a row containing two text cells. The first cell's width is the same size as the image's width and pushes the second cell out from under the image.

[image: HTML Table with large image that forces text cell to same width]

Here is an example of the preferred result. In this example the text cells have both been resized (using an image editor) to fit under the image.

[image: HTML Table with large image and text cells that are half the width of the image]

I've searched for a solution to this issue but haven't found any results that deal specifically with this particular issue. I've tried using various elements such as colspan, rowspan, and width but I must not be utilizing them correctly. What is the correct way to handle this particular issue?

Here is the HTML in question:

```
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td><img src="http://blog.bookgator.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/CreativeCommonsLogo.jpg"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>TEXT</td>
            <td>TEXT</td>
        </tr>

    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: try playing with the `colspan` attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give **`colspan="2"`** attribute to the the `<TD>` which contains Image.

The **colspan attribute**, which means “column span” will span the cell over the number of cells that is specified.

Here is the updated code:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="http://blog.bookgator.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/CreativeCommonsLogo.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TEXT</td>
        <td>TEXT</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

### Here is the Working Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hmvfem07/

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><img src="http://blog.bookgator.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/11/CreativeCommonsLogo.jpg"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>TEXT</td>
        <td>TEXT</td>
    </tr>

    </table>
```

[**fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/04aqj662/)